# How to return html5 audio/video as output inside angular filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, audio

I have this code which filter out some special text and returns audio element but it does'nt work only with html5 audio/video element how can I fix it(it works with all other html tage for eg: h1 tag etc)?

```js
angular.module('demo', ['ngSanitize']);
angular.module('demo').filter('toAudSrc',function(){
    return function (text) {
        regex = /^\*\*\*!(.*)!\*\*\*$/;
        if(regex.test(text))
            return text.replace(/^\*\*\*!(.*)!\*\*\*$/,'<audio width="200" controls preload>'+
        '<source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/mp3">'+
        '</audio>');
        else
            return text;
    }
});
angular.module('demo').controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = '***!Hola!***';
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.5.5/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='demo'>
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <h3 ng-bind-html="greeting | toAudSrc"></h3>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I read the docs again and found this solution, for anyone who has similar problem

```js
angular.module('demo', ['ngSanitize']);
angular.module('demo').filter('toAudSrc',function($sce){
    return function (text) {
        regex = /^\*\*\*!(.*)!\*\*\*$/;
        if(regex.test(text))
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text.replace(/^\*\*\*!(.*)!\*\*\*$/,'<audio width="200" controls preload>'+
        '<source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/mp3">'+
        '</audio>'));
        else
            return text;
    }
});
angular.module('demo').controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = '***!Hola!***';
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.5.5/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='demo'>
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <h3 ng-bind-html="greeting | toAudSrc"></h3>
</div>
</div>
```